Choose to build from Sources OR use existing Pre-builts in AOSP
Looking for some pointers around AOSP build i am working with.
I am trying to modify build system for this service i am adding called media-service. its currently building from the sources and working as expected and uses Android.bp file to list the target and deps.
I also got it working by copying all the dependent pre-builts and target pre-built in to this different folder with targets defined in another Android.bp, removed the original source code folder, so AOSP build picks up the prebuilts for the service.
What i am trying to do next is to be able to choose between source-code or the pre-builts to use when building lunch target given source code is not deleted.
Looking for some pointers on how to do this. What i've been figure out so far is that if use .mk files to declare these targets forpre-builts folder instead of .bp and separate .mk to define/declare targets for the source folders, i could choose which makefile to include at the build time.
but i am not sure if this is the right way and/or theres a better way to do this (soon_namespaces maybe?). Also, can i write a make rule to select one Android.bp vs other? or do i convert both the Android.bp to Android.mk?
Basically i have  a bunch of "Previous Definitions here" errors due to both source and pre-builts coexisting. i want the build system to choose one based on ENV_VARIABLE.
error: vendor/oculus/exported-prebuilts/Android.bp:1128:1: module "prebuilt_libmediadetector" already defined
       vendor/rishit/services/media-capture/libs/libmediadetector/Android.bp:11:1 <-- previous definition here

Directory structure is like this:
./vendor
    ├── ./vendor/oculus
    │   └── ./vendor/oculus/exported-services
    │       └── ./vendor/oculus/exported-services/Android.bp
    └── ./vendor/rishit
        └── ./vendor/rishit/services
            ├── ./vendor/rishit/services/Android.bp
            └── ./vendor/rishit/services/media-service
                ├── ./vendor/rishit/services/media-service/aidl
                ├── ./vendor/rishit/services/media-service/apps
                ├── ./vendor/rishit/services/media-service/include
                ├── ./vendor/rishit/services/media-service/libs
                ├── ./vendor/rishit/services/media-service/mocks
                ├── ./vendor/rishit/services/media-service/services
                ├── ./vendor/rishit/services/media-service/test
                └── ./vendor/rishit/services/media-service/tools

vendor/oculus/exported-service has the pre-builts
vendor/rishit/services/media-service has the sources
Looking for some pointers. Happy to provide mode details.
thanks in advance.

first of all stick with either mk or bp files.
mk is the old way (GNU make) to build AOSP components, bp uses ninja & soong, and is the preferred & recommended method today and in future versions of AOSP.
For example, in bp file you can use cc_prebuilt_binary module declaration to integrate a prebuilt binary, or lets say cc_binary to build it from source.
Next you can use 2 different soong namespaces for each of those modules, and then add to PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES environment variable the namespace that you want.
